# How to download API calls from chrome browser using Selenium and java or any other tool

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium

I want to verify API calls/json files that are generated at the time of performing action like save, edit from browser. We can see those API calls in Developers Tool of chrome browser under network Tab.
So I want to Test those API calls using Selenium. How can I achieve this ?

Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium doesn't have a built in functionality for you to achieve that.
Basically, if you click the Save button from browser using Selenium, you could only get the requests and responses using a 3rd party library like the Fiddler API.

Another way for you to do that is to create the requests yourself using the `HTTPRequest` or `HTTPResponse` classes (these are in C#, probably that in Java they have a different but similar name).

And using a tool, I suggest doing it with JMeter, it's open source, can do it by himself or can be integrated with Selenium.

Another options, "Selenium based" would be to use a headless browser. I know that `HTMLUnitDriver` has this built in, not sure about PhantomJS or others.